# JQL for specific condition

Tags: jira, jql

Trying to create JQL to meet the following conditions

- Show only EPICS with priority = highest AND all issue types under those epics regardless of priority.

I have tried:

```
issuetype = Epic AND priority = High
```

This just disregards all other issue types that are not highest, so I end up with just EPIC issue types

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to get [Scriptrunner for Jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/6820/scriptrunner-for-jira?hosting=cloud&tab=overview) add-on to achieve this result.

If you are on Jira Server, the query would be:

```
issuetype = Epic AND priority = Highest OR issueFunction in issuesInEpics("priority = Highest")
```

If you are on Jira Cloud, run the same query in ScriptRunner Enhanced Search window.